# Django does a useless join when filtering

Tags: django

I have an optional foreign key for a parameter:

```
class Club(models.Model):
    ...
    locationid = models.ForeignKey(location_models.Location, null=True)
    ...
```

I want to find entries of club where this foreignkey is not set. Here's the ORM query:

```
print Club.objects.filter(locationid=None).only('name').query
```

Produces

```sql
SELECT `club_club`.`id`, `club_club`.`name` FROM `club_club`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `location_location`
ON (`club_club`.`locationid_id` = `location_location`.`id`)
WHERE `location_location`.`id` IS NULL
```

Same query is produced when I do `filter(locationid_id__isnull=True)`
What I want is to query on `locationid_id` without involving a `JOIN`. I know I can write raw SQL, but is there an ORM-al way of doing this?

Comment: So you tried `filter(locationid_id__isnull=True)` and yet it still generated `WHERE 'location_location'.'id' IS NULL` instead of `WHERE 'location_id' IS NULL`?

Comment: @MikeDeSimone correct :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be quite a [persistent issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10790), and the patch that fixed it had other side effects, so it never got applied to a release version of Django.

A solution to this is to use the `extra` method. This will require raw SQL, but only a limited amount and using SQL standards, so it should be compatible with all SQL databases:

```
location_null = '`%s`.`%s` IS NULL' % (Club._meta.db_table, Club.locationid.field.column)
Club.objects.extra(where=[location_null])
```

You can add this as a manager/queryset method for a more DRY solution.

The other option is to just take the performance hit. This is what I would recommend, unless benchmarking shows that the performance hit really is unacceptable in your specific case.

Comment: Will probably stick with the latter option not to confuse anyone else who might be reading this code later.